# Importing Swampy (Python learning module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, swampy

I'm working on"ThinkPython" and in chapter4 we're asked to download swampy (a learning module). Well I followed the [instructions here](http://www.thinkpython.com/swampy) and I installed it, but when I try to import in IDLE(Python GUI) using: `import swampy.TurtleWorld`, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import swampy.TurtleWorld
ImportError: No module named 'swampy'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you installed it for the Python version you are using? You might need to do `easy-install-3` or something similar instead of `easy-install`. What system are you running on?

Comment: @filmor Yeah I checked it.

Comment: Nada - I would go through the `swampy` tag and look at some of the previous questions and answers - this seems to be an oft asked question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the module have not installed correctly - Python doesnt see it in its modules path. What's your $PYTHONPATH, and what's your OS, and have you checked if the module is in your $PYTHONPATH?